# Specify minimum trigger frequency for recording audio in Python

Tags: python, audio, triggers

I'm writing a script for sound-activated recording in Python using pyaudio. I want to trigger a 5s recording after a sound that is above a prespecified volume and frequency. I've managed to get the volume part working but don't know how to specify the minimum trigger frequency (I'd like it to trigger at frequencies above 10kHz, for example):

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from array import array
import time
 
FORMAT=pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS=1
RATE=44100
CHUNK=1024
RECORD_SECONDS=5

audio=pyaudio.PyAudio() 

stream=audio.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS, 
                  rate=RATE,
                  input=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

nighttime=True

while nighttime:
     data=stream.read(CHUNK)
     data_chunk=array('h',data)
     vol=max(data_chunk)
     if(vol>=3000):
         print("recording triggered")
         frames=[]
         for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
             data = stream.read(CHUNK)
             frames.append(data)
         print("recording saved")
         # write to file
         words = ["RECORDING-", time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), ".wav"]
         FILE_NAME= "".join(words) 
         wavfile=wave.open(FILE_NAME,'wb')
         wavfile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
         wavfile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
         wavfile.setframerate(RATE)
         wavfile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
         wavfile.close()
     # check if still nighttime
     nighttime=True 
 
 stream.stop_stream()
 stream.close()
 audio.terminate()
```

I'd like to add to the line `if(vol>=3000):` something like `if(vol>=3000 and frequency>10000):` but I don't know how to set up `frequency`. How to do this?

Comment: I hope our chat explained all the caveats. In essence: find the peak above 10 khz and / or high-pass filter. Complete code to find peaks in frequencies: https://github.com/tracek/audio-explorer/blob/master/audioexplorer/specprop.py (likely you will find more code of interest). Accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the frequency of a signal you can compute Fourier transform, thus switching to frequency domain (`freq` in the code). Your next step is to compute relative amplitude of the signal (`amp`) . The latter is proportional to the sound volume.

```
spec = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(audio_array))
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(audio_array), d=1 / sampling_freq)
spec = np.abs(spec)
amp = spec / spec.sum()
```

Mind that `3000` isn't a sound volume either. The true sound volume information was lost when the signal was digitalised. Now you only work with relative numbers, so you can just check if e.g. 1/3 of energy in a frame is above 10 khz.

Here's some code to illustrate the concept:

```
idx_above_10khz = np.argmax(freq > 10000)
amp_below_10k = amp[:idx_above_10khz].sum()
amp_above_10k = amp[idx_above_10khz:].sum()
```

Now you could specify that from certain ratio of `amp_below_10k / amp_above_10k` you should trigger your program.

Comment: Great, thanks! How do I work this into the `if` statement to trigger a recording? `if(vol>=3000 and max(freq) > threshold):`? Can I use `amp` to specify that it has to be over a certain amplitude as well? `if(vol>=3000 and max(freq) > threshold and amp > threshold2):`

Comment: Also what is `X`?

Comment: @Thomas `X` was an artifact from renaming variables, fixed now. You should definitively use `amp`, as this, in combination with `freq`, will allow you to find if there's significant enough signal around 10 kz. `vol` gives you overall signal strength and tells nothing about how it is distributed in the spectrum.

Comment: OK perfect, thanks. This all looks good but I can't get it to work - see above edit. Is my code correct?

Comment: @Thomas 10 kHz is a very high frequency. Make sure you plan high frequency and that your mic can actually properly capture it. Try with e.g. 2 kHz, that should be easier. The code looks correct.

Comment: The mic I'm using is ultrasonic with 384000 sampling rate (for recording bats). I'm testing both with that mic and with a normal mic (at appropriate sampling rates), same result. Normal mic is able to pick up tones up to 20kHz (tested in Audacity playing tones from tone generator on smartphone). Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Just tested at 2kHz, same result.

Comment: @Thomas Share the recording.

Comment: I'm testing it live from the mic but here are some example clips https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ybbq61l70r9on0/sample%20recordings.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Thomas The 12 khz file has almost all energy in lower ends of the spetrum. The algorithm as proposed won't work for detecting sharp peaks as in that sample. There are other methods, but now we are going well beyond the original question. You can open a new one, attach link to that recording, plot spectrum and show what you'd like to detect. The code as proposed here works, but for different problems, where energy is in the higher ends of the spectrum.

Comment: Ah right I see. Would it be possible to apply a high pass filter? I don't need to record anything below 10kHz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234909/discussion-between-lukasz-tracewski-and-thomas).