# Spy on the sounds inside the Window 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, system

I want to spy on the sounds inside the system (windows 10), and if the sound exceeds 250Hz, do something,

how can I do that with python?

I tried to search for it and found the recording of the external and internal audio in a file, but I don't want that.

Comment: Maybe this could help you ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344928/specify-minimum-trigger-frequency-for-recording-audio-in-python)

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @wondergrandma This is almost what I wanted, but it listens to the microphone, not the system. How can I change that?